# Autocomplete Suggestion on <p> Tag Without Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make autocomplete (without dropdown) to a contenteditable paragraph tag. How to select remaining suggested letters in contenteditable p tag with javascript/jQuery while user typing?

[image]

```
// On typing
$(document).on('input', '.cell-input', function(e) {
    var userInput = e.target.innerText;

    // Suggested 'Bond' to user, because user typed (assumption) 'B'
    e.target.innerText = 'Bond';

    // Select
    $(e.target).selectText(1, 3);
});

// To select
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(startPos, endPos){
    var doc = document;
    var element = this[0];

    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    }
    else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();        
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
};
```

Select all is working fine. Then I tried adding:

```
selection.moveEnd("character", endPos);
selection.moveStart("character", startPos);
```

or

```
range.moveEnd("character", endPos);
range.moveStart("character", startPos);
```

.. but no luck. Am I in the right direction? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Using [setStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setStart) and [setEnd()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setEnd)

```js
$(document).on('input', '.cell-input', function(e) {
  var userInput = e.target.innerText;

  // Suggested 'Bond' to user, because user typed (assumption) 'B'
  e.target.innerText = 'Bond';

  // Select
  $(e.target).selectText(1, 4);
});

// To select
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(startPos, endPos) {
  var doc = document;
  var element = this[0];

  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(element);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(element.firstChild, startPos);
    range.setEnd(element.firstChild, endPos);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="cell-input" contenteditable="true">B</p>
```

**Note:** Using `element.firstChild` may not work with HTML child nodes

Comment: Because I'm not using input element but p tag, so setSelectionRange results `input.setSelectionRange is not a function`.

Comment: @JeafGilbert Sorry for that. Check now the answer is updated